# How generate new doctrine models without delete doctrine models classes with my code addition

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I build zend app with doctrine.

The problem is when I add new tables to database and I should generate doctrine models, because I add my own code to Doctine generated classes, I don't want to delete them.
I solve this problem like that:

1. copy old generated doctine models classes to other folder
2. generate doctrine models from database
3. remove same new doctrine models class with old

I think my solution can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Only base classes are overwritten when they already do exist.

Do not modify them. Put your custom code in models extending base classes, so your code will keep unchanged upon next model generation.

You may take a look at *service layer* as well, as a method for separating your model layer.

And one more advice: if you repeat the same thing over and over, it is best to automate this, eg. using [Phing](http://phing.info).

Answer (score 0):

here is my doctrine CLI the main idea to

```
   'generateBaseClasses'   => true,
   'generateTableClasses'  => false,
```

there for doctrine cli would only recreate the base classes only and you would save your work

cheers

tawfek daghistani

```
<?php
echo "Hello Tawfek ! , Howdy ?? \n";
/**
 * Doctrine CLI
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../"));
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
//Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '../library',get_include_path(), "/home/------/Sites/font/library/" )));
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

// Read in the application.ini bootstrap for Doctrine
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');

// Create the configuration array
$config = $application->getOption('doctrine');
// (Note you can have all of these in application.ini aswell)
$config['generate_models_options'] = array(
    // Define the PHPDoc Block in the generated classes
    'phpDocPackage'         =>'Font',
    'phpDocSubpackage'      =>'Models',
    'phpDocName'            =>'Tawfek Daghistani',
    'phpDocEmail'           =>'-----@-----.com',
    'phpDocVersion'         =>'1.0',
    // Define whats what and named how, where.
    'suffix'                => '.php',
    'pearStyle'             => true,
    'baseClassPrefix'       => 'Base_',
    // Unless you have created a custom class or want Default_Model_Base_Abstract
    'baseClassName'         => 'Doctrine_Record',
    // Leave this empty as specifying 'Base' will create Base/Base
    'baseClassesDirectory'  => NULL,
    // Should make it Zend Framework friendly AFAIK
    'classPrefix'           => 'Dagho_Model_',
    'classPrefixFiles'      => false,
    'generateBaseClasses'   => true,
    'generateTableClasses'  => false,
    'packagesPath'          => APPLICATION_PATH . '/models',
    'packagesFolderName'    => 'packages',

);

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
$cli->run($_SERVER['argv']);
?>
```